# How to accept any word in routes in nodejs?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

```
router.get('/s3Image/:folderName1/:folderName/:fileName',checkNewrelic, s3Image.downloadS3Image)
```

at here how to minimize nested folder structure for `:folderName1/:folderName/` with single special character or word

need single special character or word to minimize multiple routes for multiple folder structure.

Comment: Hi, please note, `mysql` tag is not applicable here, in this specific code. Please remove it!

Comment: Can you further describe your problem? These routes already support special characters or single words in each of the last 3 components.